# Qual a forma correta de concatenar strings em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

Comecei a aprender Python e me disseram que não devia concatenar as strings com `,` mas usar o método `.format()`. E no JavaScript e correto usar `+` ou `,` para concatenar as strings ou há uma maneira mais recomendada e mais usada?

Comment: Concatenar em que contexto? Pura e simples, duas *strings*?

Comment: Só isso mesmo. É que comecei a achar feio isso: str1+" "+str2.

Comment: @bigown Saberia dizer se existe algum lugar no site pra postar perguntas meio fora do escopo como essa?

Comment: Eu não diria que ela é fora de escopo, talvez simples demais :) Então é aqui mesmo.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

É possível utilizar também "template string" para isso:

```
var str1 = 'hello';
var str2 = 'world';
var res = `${str1} ${str2}`;
```

Nessa caso onde são apenas 2 strings, não faz tanto sentido utilizar, mas em concateções maiores, é bem interessante.

Template string faz parte da ES6/ES2015, alguns navegadores mais antigos podem não suportar.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings
http://wesbos.com/javascript-template-strings/

Comment: to nem ai com navegadores antigos, to igual o whatsapp pros celulares antigos.

Comment: Simplesmente amei essas template strings.

Answer (score 12):

Não tem nada feio ou errado em fazer um simples `str1+" "+str2`. Pode usar sem problemas. É simples e eficiente. Não tem motivos técnicos para escolher uma forma, é só estilo mesmo.

Apesar que feio depende de gosto, eu acho qualquer outra forma feia, mais longa e até menos intuitiva quando bate o olho rápido. Escolha um e seja consistente, não fique mudando a forma.

Poderia haver problemas se fizer muitas concatenações dentro de um laço, mas até isto o JS otimiza, então até o uso de `str += str2` é adequando em um laço.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 8):

```
var str1 = "Hello ";
var str2 = "world!";
var res = str1.concat(str2);
```

**Resultado:** Hello world!

Referência: https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/jsref_concat_string.asp

**Outra forma, com `+`:**

```
var res = str1+str2;
```

Comment: Qual forma voce recomenda, concat ou simplesmente o +?