# Exibir mensagem na tela a partir de um objeto

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
obj = {nome: 'Elis', sobrenome: 'Regina', profissao: 'cantora'}
```

Preciso escrever o a mensagem na tela:

> "Elis Regina foi uma grande cantora".

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você sabe usar o operador `.`? Por exemplo, `objeto.campo`? Conhece a função `alert`?

Comment: `document.write(obj.nome + ' ' + obj.sobrenome + ' foi uma grande ' + obj.profissao)`

Answer (score 1):

Robert, para obter o resultado esperado, precisa concatenar os itens do objeto e exibir em um `alert`, por exemplo.

Note que para conseguir extrair o nome do objeto, precisamos indicar qual o nome do objeto, e depois qual atributo queremos, por exemplo, para recuperar somente o nome, podemos fazer assim:

```js
obj = {nome: 'Elis', sobrenome: 'Regina', profissao: 'cantora'}

console.log(obj.nome);
```

<sup>Para saber o que é console.log, [clique aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38057/o-que-%C3%A9-console-log)</sup>

---

Então chamando cada atributo e concatenando, temos o resultado:

```js
obj = {nome: 'Elis', sobrenome: 'Regina', profissao: 'cantora'}

//Elis Regina foi uma grande cantora.
alert(obj.nome +' '+ obj.sobrenome + ' foi uma grande '+obj.profissao + '.');
```

<sup>Para saber o que é concatenação, [clique aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231359/qual-a-forma-correta-de-concatenar-strings-em-javascript)</sup>

Comment: Escreva uma função em Javascript que peça ao usuário para digitar seu nome e depois escreva seu nome no console em uma mensagem de boas-vindas. Por exemplo, se o nome do usuário for Alex, a mensagem deve ser: "Olá Alex, seja bem-vindo!". Dica de resolução: use a função prompt() do Javascript.

Comment: @RobertOliveira Qual parte da resposta você não entendeu?

Comment: Marque essa resposta como resolvida no simbolo de "Correto" acima. Isso que vc escreveu já é outra dúvida. E por favor, pergunte com suas palavras e não como uma lista execícios. Poste suas dúvidas.

Answer (score 1):

Podes criar uma função que consuma esse tipo de objetos e retorne a String completa. O ideal seria teres o género no objeto assim podias mudar dinamicamente o `uma` para `um`.

Exemplo:

```js
const descrever = obj => `${obj.nome} ${obj.sobrenome} foi ${obj.genero === 'F' ? 'uma' : 'um'} grande ${obj.profissao}`;

const Elis = {
  nome: 'Elis',
  sobrenome: 'Regina',
  profissao: 'cantora',
  genero: 'F'
};
const Vivaldi = {
  nome: 'Antonio',
  sobrenome: 'Vivaldi',
  profissao: 'compositor',
  genero: 'M'
};

console.log(descrever(Elis)); // Elis Regina foi uma grande cantora
console.log(descrever(Vivaldi)); // Antonio Vivaldi foi um grande compositor
```