# Como adicionar variáveis concatenadas em um link de url?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tenho o seguindo código:

```
var config = {
    method: "post",
    url:
      "https://my-api-link/v2/sessions?email=myemail@gmail.com&token=EAD7FC0724EF4254FG34323D62FEF2",
    headers: {}
  };
```

Eu queria salvar o **email** e o **token** que são variáveis globais,pensei nisso:

```
const email = proccess.env.EMAIL
const token = proccess.env.TOKEN

var config = {
    method: "post",
    url:
      "https://my-api-link/v2/sessions?email=$email&token=$token",
    headers: {}
  };
```

Tentei dessa outra forma:

```
const email = proccess.env.EMAIL
const token = proccess.env.TOKEN

var config = {
    method: "post",
    url:
      "https://my-api-link/v2/sessions?email="+email"&token="+token"",
    headers: {}
  };
```

Porém também sem sucesso,gostaria de pedir ajuda para resolver isso,eu tentei de outras formas também,porém sem sucesso!

Desde já grato!

Comment: O ultimo `""` não precisa e a variável `email` deveria estar entre `+` ficando assim:    `"https://my-api-link/v2/sessions?email=" + email + "&token=" + token,`

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual a forma correta de concatenar strings em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231359/qual-a-forma-correta-de-concatenar-strings-em-javascript)

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poderia tentar a seguinte sintaxe:

```
const email = proccess.env.EMAIL
const token = proccess.env.TOKEN

var config = {
    method: "post",
    url:
      `https://my-api-link/v2/sessions?email=${email}&token=${token}`,
    headers: {}
  };
```

Repare que em minha solução eu utilizei o modelo de interpolação de strings por template string.
Para utilizar o template string basta iniciar a string com `acento grave` (<kbd>`</kbd>).

Depois para  interpolar a string basta utilizar um `${valor}` com o valor a ser concatenado.

[Mais informações aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO! DONE!